# Parse XML response from PHP CURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, twilio

I am trying to use an API that returns the following structure

```
    <TwilioResponse>
     <Call>
     <Sid>CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38</Sid>
     <DateCreated>Tue, 10 Aug 2010 08:02:17 +0000</DateCreated>
     <DateUpdated>Tue, 10 Aug 2010 08:02:47 +0000</DateUpdated>
     <ParentCallSid/>
     <AccountSid>AC5ef872f6da5a21de157d80997a64bd33</AccountSid>
     <To>+14153855708</To>
     <From>+14158141819</From>
     <PhoneNumberSid></PhoneNumberSid>
     <Status>completed</Status>
     <StartTime>Tue, 10 Aug 2010 08:02:31 +0000</StartTime>
     <EndTime>Tue, 10 Aug 2010 08:02:47 +0000</EndTime>
     <Duration>16</Duration>
     <Price>-0.03000</Price>
     <Direction>outbound-api</Direction>
    </Call>
   </TwilioResponse>
```

I can get to the XML data by using CURL which works fine like this:

```
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url."/Accounts/{$accountSid}/Calls");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
```

however once I get the data back as XML I try and put it into a simpleXML element and return it back to the page that called this function as follows:

```
    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($response);
    if($xml)
{
  return $xml;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

When I return the XML to the page that called the function, I can see a whole lot of simpleXMLElement Objects if I do a print_r() but when I try and do a foreach($xml->TwilioResponse->call as $call) I get nothing and it does not seem like I can actually drill into the data at all.

Can someone help me and point out where I am going wrong with this? It has been driving me absolutely crazy for the past couple of hours.

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are two problems with `$xml->TwilioResponse->call`.

1. `$xml` contains the `TwilioResponse` element (the "document element"), `$xml->TwilioResponse` is incorrect.
2. (XML and) SimpleXML element names are case-sensitive, `call` should be `Call`.

Give `$xml->Call` a spin.